# How to determine the vector of the perpendicular direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Knowing the points **P1** and **P2**, I need the perpendicular direction vector (`P1` and `P2` are `Vector3`)

I try:

```
var direction = Vector3.Cross(P1, P2).normalized;
```

But that is not the correct answer.

How to do it correctly?

[image]

Comment: You can't get a perpendicular vector out of 2 positions in 3D .. there are basically infinite possible result vectors rotating around the axis (P2 - P1) ... you need two **direction vectors** .. what you are doing is get a perpendicular vector to the two vectors `P2 - worldOrigin` and `P1 - worldOrigin` .. That positions in Unity are also stored as `Vector3` is more a convinience

Comment: @derHugo Right. I have not visualized that in 3D there can be an infinite number of such perpendiculars. I transferred it to a 2D plane and set this direction. `var d = Vector2.Perpendicular(P2 - P1).normalized;`. Thanks for the tip

Comment: alternatively you would simply need that other vector (basically the direction in which we are looking onto your drawing) and then use `var d = Vector3.Cross((P2 - P1), lookDirection).normalized;`

Answer (score 1):

So to do what you want to do, first you need to calculate the vector.
You are passing 2 points as input when in reality you need 2 vectors.
So first you should calculate the vector:

```
var direction = P2 - P1
```

After doing that, you can calculate the cross product:

```
var perpendicular = Vector3.Cross(direction, Vector3.Up).normalized;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you write what you need more clearly, my reputation is not enough for writing comments so ı will just write here.

As ı understood you need a vector perpendicular to the line [P1, P2], but at 3 dimensions there is infinite number of perpendicular vectors to [P1, P2]
(Imagine a perpendicular vector to [P1, P2] and rotate it in your mind. There will be infinite vector perpendicular to [P1, P2])

At 2 dimensions there will be just one perpendicular line for any line. İf the slope (Y/X) of a line is 3, the perpendicular line's slope will be 1/3.

If you want a vector perpendicular to two vectors (not dots) you can use the cross-product of two vectors. Cross product will give you a vector that is perpendicular to both vectors but it may not be what you want.

I don't know is there any built-in method for these. If you write why you need this it will be easy to help.